# i am working to create a function but this code appears TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, list, function

```
def num():
    while True:
        n= int(input("donnez le num"))
        if n > 0:
            break

    T=([int]*n)
    for i in range (0,n):
        n[i]=i
num()
print(T)
```

The code is mainly about creating a table after asking the user a number
in this table i want to fill it with number and descending example: the user puts 10 desired result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGuJy.png)

[this is the outpout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w62VC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of issues in your code

1. your code is not returning any value , so T is not defined outside of function
2. `n[i]` meant to be `T[i]`
3. you need to change the range to n+1
4. you can shorten/optimize your code as follows

so:

```
def num():
    while True:
        n= int(input("donnez le num"))
        if n > 0:
            break
    return [i for i in range(0,n+1)]

print(num())
```

et voila, output:

```
donnez le num 10
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```